# ¿Como generar gráficos estadísticos parametrizables con laravel?

Tags: laravel, highcharts, chart.js

Saludos comunidad estoy viendo y analizando algunas opciones estoy tratando de implementar gráficos estadísticos parametrizables o bien personalizables, la verdad no se me ocurre como crear esto, es decir que pueda graficar dependido de las opciones que elija, entonces mi gráfico tomaría esos valores y los graficaria, imagen a modo de ejemplo:

[image: ejemplo]

lo que yo logre por ejemplo son estos gráficos, pero esto es una estadística algo "rigida"

[image: mis graficos]

En el gráfico de barras se visualizan las ordenes de produccion de un taller en los 2 últimos meses, un ejemplo seria comparar con otro mes permitiendo elegir ese mes mediante un select y luego graficar.

En el grafico doughnut se observan los estados de cada orden (rojo  no terminado, amarillo en proceso, verde terminado).

estaría bueno que el gráfico permita graficar a través de opciones que el usuario pueda seleccionar o cargar.
Disculpen que no sea una pregunta especifica, a lo mejor alguien ya paso por este tipo de reportes estadísticos y me puede ayudar ya sea con algún ejemplo.
Voy estar atentos a sus respuestas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

Personalmente no he trabajado con highcharts, pero sí con chartsjs. Lo más sencillo sería crear un formulario HTML que envíe una petición AJAX usando JQuery, en la parte de success, una función debería actualizar el valor de las gráficas y llamar a update. No sé exactamente la estructura de tu sistema, pero sería algo así:

```
$("#formulario").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // evita que se envíe la petición HTTP normal

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(), 
        success: function(response)
        {
            grafica.data.datasets[0].data = response.datos
            grafica.data.labels = response.etiquetas 
            grafica.update()
        }
    });
});
```

Donde gráfica es el objeto de la gráfica que quieres modificar.
Habría también que recibir esta llamada en el archivo de rutas y enviarla a un controlador que se ocupe de recolectar los datos de la base de datos.

Comment: Saludos @Gamopo, he actualizado mi pregunta podrias revisarla, quizas podrias ayudarme este es el enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/339925/gr%c3%a1fico-din%c3%a1mico-con-chart-js-y-vue-js